# mpdf is direct downloading webserver

Tags: php, tcpdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate pdf reports in PHP, when I test on my developing PC using XAMPP the pdf report is showing in the browser, but when I host it to the webserver, it is not opening in browser and start downloading.

here is my code

```
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$html = 'some html'
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 1;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullwidth','continuous');
$mpdf->output();
exit();
```

what is the wrong with webserver???

> Edit

I have found this is due to IDM installed, how to prevent IDM to download the file

Comment: there has to be an error generated, your configuration must have turned off to display errors, so your error should be in a logfile

Comment: I have the same problem like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651175/pdf-are-download-with-idm-show-it-without-convert-to-image

Answer (score 0):

maybe the server's sent different header information.

```
// set these two header to open the file in your browser
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; yourfilename.pdf");

include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$html = 'some html'
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 1;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullwidth','continuous');
$mpdf->output();
exit();
```